# Ld wrong symbol

Tags: c++, python, boost, linker, symbols

I'm buildnig application with boost.python library. I want to link it. Here is the code:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

// Boost.python definitions to expose classes to Python
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(arrayClasses) {
}
```

And makefile for it:

```
PYTHON = /usr/include/python2.7

BOOST_INC = /usr/include
BOOST_LIB = /usr/lib

TARGET = arrayClasses

$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
    g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic \
    $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python \
    -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 \
    -o $(TARGET).so

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).cpp
    g++ -I$(PYTHON) -I$(BOOST_INC) -c -fPIC $(TARGET).cpp
```

When I compile it I get:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic \
    arrayClasses.o -L/usr/lib -lboost_python \
    -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 \
    -o arrayClasses.so
/usr/bin/ld: arrayClasses.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `init_module_arrayClasses()' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
arrayClasses.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's wrong is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have `-fPIC` for your `.o` target, but not
>   for the `.so` target. See if adding it helps.

**Edit:** Ignore that. This compiles for me on a 32-bit Ubuntu system using Python 2.6 and Boost 1.44. As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams pointed out, you should probably check if your Python and Boost libraries were compiled for the same architecture.